# phonegap place folder in the right place so I can use VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cordova

I have been here: http://phonegap.com/install/  and downloaded the latest phonegap release.
I am not sure where to put it, so that VS can find it, when creating a new project. Has anyone any idea about where to place it? For now, I tried placing it in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE, and this is not the right place, obviously.

I know that one can install phonegap using the commandline, but I rather not do this, since I already tried, and had issues with environment variables. Furthermore, from what I found out on stackoverflow regarding using the commandline, several people did not advice this, based on their experience. So please, if you know how I make it work so that I can use VS, please share. I see that the phonegap folder that I downloaded from phonegap site, contains IDEs for several platforms.

Thanks in advance

Ps. I am trying to achieve something semilar to this: http://anindita9.wordpress.com/tag/visual-studio-phonegap/
But it's just that this tutorial doesn't work for me, since I have VS12, and also the folder structure is totally different